# Javascript var as Razor parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This seems really simple but I have searched everywhere and can't find an easy way to do this. I have a textbox with a search button and I am calling an action result that will search the database for a matching value to what is in my textbox. Everything works as expected except that my action result (called from razor within a javascript click function) requires a parameter of what is in the textbox (var policy) and I cannot find a way to use that value within my razor action result call.

This is my textbox and the javascript that handles it. "PolicyNum = " is where I am trying to pass in the value of "var policy"

Textbox:

```
<span class="k-textbox k-space-right" style="width: 185px">
    <input id="polText" type="text" />
    <a id="polSearch" href="#" class="k-icon k-i-search">&nbsp;</a>
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#polSearch").click(function () {
        var policy = $("#polText").val();
        location = '@Url.Action("SearchByPolicy", new { policyNum =  })';
    });
});
```

This code is all located in my main view.

Comment: Couldn't you simply set `href` to your action url? No javascript required.

Comment: Not if the others are correct in saying that razor will render before the html. This works for the link but I still need to grab the parameter out of the texbox.

Comment: Actually, Razor renders the html and javascript on the server, then sends it to the browser where it is parsed, executed and displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are NOT going to achieve what you want this way. Your confusion is understandable: Razor variables render BEFORE HTML and JS execute.

You would be be would be better server using a URL approach

```
$(function () {
    $("#polSearch").click(function () {
        var policy = $("#polText").val();
        location = '{Controller}/SearchByPolicy/" + policy';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instead of `a` element.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller", 
    new { policy = ""}, 
    new { id = "polSearch", class="k-icon k-i-search"})
```

script

```
$(function () {
    $("#polSearch").click(function () {
        var policy = $("#polText").val();
        location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```

Comment: clever. deals with the pre-render icky.

Answer (score 0):

Razor runs serverside, JS clientside. You need to supply a parameterless URL in Razor and set the ID in it using JS. Something like:

```
location = '@Url.Action("SearchByPolicy")' + policy;
```